# How to generate a due date using date of birth?

Tags: php, phtml

I had created the date of birth field and submit button.When I select the date of birth it has to generate the due date with the increment of 2 weeks,6 weeks

Ex:if the date is 1/1/2015 it has to show the due date as 22/1/2015

How i has to do this.Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a magento issue but take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

You can use JavaScript, no jQuery required:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Comment: But I have a confusion as date of birth field is in another file and due date field is in another file how can I add the code and print in due date field.Please suggest me